# How to fix the position of a Kivy layout when the screen resolution changes as the program is open?

Tags: python, kivy

I have built a user interface with Kivy that appears correctly when the program starts up, but if I plug in a new monitor (or drag to an extended monitor), everything disappears under the window, but I can see part of my work when I maximize the window. How do I position my program to the start of the window?

I have tried to match the main layout top value to the window top value every second, and I have tried to reset the position of the main layout every second.

My kivy file

```
#:import inch kivy.metrics.inch

<Questionaire>:
    #column_gl: ColumnGL
    outer_column_gl: OuterColumnGL
    cols: 2

    GridLayout:
        id: OuterColumnGL
        cols: 1
        size_hint_x: None
        width: inch(2)
        GridLayout:
            id: ColumnGL
            cols: 2
            size_hint_y: .9
            Button:
                size_hint_x: None
                width: inch(.1)
            Button:
                text: 'stuff'
        Button:
            size_hint_y: .1
            text: 'more stuff'
```

My attempt to fix it

```
def fix_screen(*args):
    self.y = 0
Clock.schedule_interval(fix_screen, .5)
```

This is what comes up when I first open the program.
[image: This is what comes up when I first open the program.]

This is what comes up as soon as I drag my window to an extended monitor (Everything appears to have disappeared).
[image: This is what comes up as soon as I drag my window to an extended monitor (Everything appears to have disappeared).]

Here is my maximized window on the extended monitor (The y position is wrong).
[image: Here is my maximized window on the extended monitor (The y position is wrong).]

Comment: Your `fix_screen()` method will not work since there is no `self` in that method as defined. Instead of using `schedule_interval`, you can use `Window.bind(on_draw=fix_screen)` to call your `fix_screen` method whenever the app is drawn.

Comment: self is the root widget. When I print out the y position of the root and the window, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using size_hint_x or size_hint_x allows you to set the size of your widgets relative to their parent widgets. Using ''pos_hint: {'x': val, 'y': val}'' will set the position of the widget to their parent widgets. Since size_hint, and pos_hint both are relative to their parent widgets, the values for the x and y are in a range from 0-1.

I would recommend utilizing size_hint_x: 0-1 rather than width for your buttons so they will automatically adjust to a changing resolution. I will come up with a sample to help you out.

Sizing and position are best done in the kv language whether you use builder or a .kv file. The added class and function are not needed to have reactive widgets. Let me know if you need more clarification or have any other questions about kivy.

Again I would recommend this following your widgets if you would like them to autoscale:

```
size_hint_x: 0.00-1.00
size_hint_y: 0.00-1.00
pos_hint: {'x': 0.00-1.00, 'y': 0.00-1.00}
```

An example that should show you how it works, although I doubt you need all the extra imports as this was to show consistency when changing resolutions:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand') #Prevent red dots from populating the screen with right clicks
Config.set('graphics','resizable',0) #Self-explanatory, prevents you from resizing the window
Config.write() #Writes the Config settings for the application

Builder.load_string("""
<One>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint_x: .5
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        GridLayout:
            id: OuterColumnGL
            cols: 1
            size_hint_x: .2
            GridLayout:
                id: ColumnGL
                cols: 2
                size_hint_y: .9
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: .3
                Button:
                    text: 'stuff'
            Button:
                size_hint_y: .1
                text: 'more stuff'
    Button:
        text: 'Change Res'
        size_hint_x:.2
        size_hint_y: .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .75, 'y': .05}
        on_release: root.enlarge()
<Two>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint_x: .5
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        GridLayout:
            id: OuterColumnGL
            cols: 1
            size_hint_x: .2
            GridLayout:
                id: ColumnGL
                cols: 2
                size_hint_y: .9
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: .3
                Button:
                    text: 'stuff'
            Button:
                size_hint_y: .1
                text: 'more stuff'
    Button:
        text: 'Change Res'
        size_hint_x:.2
        size_hint_y: .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .75, 'y': .05}
        on_release: root.shrink()
""")

class One(Screen):
    def enlarge(self):
        Window.size = (500, 600)
        sm.current = 'two'
class Two(Screen):
    def shrink(self):
        Window.size = (300, 400)
        sm.current = 'one'
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(One(name='one'))
sm.add_widget(Two(name='two'))

class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 400)
        Window.left = 750
        Window.top = 40
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

Comment: Very descriptive, but still, when I bring the window over to another monitor, it makes everything disappear like in the picture examples I posted.

Comment: Did you try running the script I posted? The window should resize only when you hit that button I added to show the hints in effect for size and position. However if that did not work, maybe change the y position when you refresh the screen with your method? If you post your entire script I may be able to offer more help

Comment: Also you have ```GridLayout:
            id: ColumnGL
            cols: 2
            size_hint_y: .9``` so it wont reach the top of your window regardless once you maximize your window, maybe change that to ```size_hint_y: 1``` and see if thats a solution for you